# XPath to find table row based on containing field with associated label and value

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

Here's what I have right now:

```
//tr[.//*[@id = string(../label[.='foo']/@for) and @value='bar']]
```

I know this works:

```
//tr[.//label[.='foo']/@for]
```

I also confirmed that the `string()` function works as expected, but it seems to be hung up on matching the `string()` against the `id` attribute. Any idea why?

Here's a bit of X[HT]ML that should match this - it should find the second row:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <label for="thing1">foo</label>
     <input id="thing1" value="not-bar" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <label for="thing2">foo</label>
     <input id="thing2" value="bar" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample of XML you are dealing with?

Comment: Also you have a syntax error. One square bracket is missing. You should use //tr[.//*[@id = string(.//label[.='foo']/@for)] and @value='bar']. Still looks like a rather inefficient expression. May be we can provide a better one, if we see the XML.

Comment: @Flack: updated the question with the missing right bracket and a bit of XML.

Comment: @wuputah: I think that `label` elements are going to be siblings of the form control that they refer... So, first I would use `../label` instead of `.//label`

Comment: @wuputah: Second. If there is more than one `label` with 'foo' string value, then `string()` function will take only the first in document order.

Comment: @Alejandro: Ah, that is the core of the problem then. Any idea on how to get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//tr[*/input
    [@id = ../label[.='foo']/@for and @value='bar']
    ]
```

Looks sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the core of the problem was the `string()` function and the sibling reference to label, as you changed here. Changed that and it's working!